# NetLogo: Find detailed information on "random-gamma" calculation error and its range in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, gamma-distribution, gamma, gamma-function

I want to look for detailed information such as random-gamma calculation error and its range. But at the moment I have not found yet. If anyone knows it and the risk with somewhat range caused by the random-gamma syntax in NetLogo, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: source code is at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-core/src/main/agent/Gamma.java , comments at the top explain the code's provenance